# SELECT only rows that contain no repeating values

Tags: sql

**Context**

I have a table that has a column that acts like a "key" value. The same key value could appear in multiple rows and I want to `SELECT` only rows that contain keys that don't appear in multiple rows. For example, if input table is:

```
key  |  col1  |  col2  |  other columns
_______________________________________
1       1337     1338
1       1339     1340
2       1341     1342
3       1343     1344
3       1345     1346
4       1347     1348
5       1349     1350
5       1351     1352
5       1353     1354
```

Output should be:

```
key  |  col1  |  col2  |  other columns
_______________________________________
2       1341     1342
4       1347     1348
```

---

**Question**

Can I do this efficiently without populating a third table?

---

**What I Tried**

```
SELECT key, col1, col2, other columns
FROM input_t
WHERE COUNT(col1) = 1
GROUP BY key
```

However this is not a valid query. Also what if col1 is NULL? I still want the row (key, col2, other columns).

```
SELECT key, col1, col2, other columns
FROM input_t
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(col1) = 1
```

Not a valid query either.

I have tried using `DISTINCT` but that doesn't ignore the keys that appear multiple times. It also does not make logical sense for me to aggregate the other columns.

Comment: Do you have a unique id column of some sort?

Comment: Also, which dialect of SQL are you using?  SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry for not specifying, I'm using Presto in a highly modified work environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `NOT IN` if key is never `NULL`

```
SELECT key, col1, col2, other columns
FROM input_t
WHERE key NOT IN (
   SELECT key
   FROM input_t
   GROUP BY key
   HAVING COUNT(col1) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation, if you like:

```
SELECT key, min(col1) as col1, min(col2) as col2, . . .
FROM input_t
GROUP BY key
HAVING COUNT(col1) = 1;
```

With only one row, `min()` is the value.

For efficiency, the best is probably:

```
select t.*
from input_t t
where not exists (select 1
                  from input_t t2
                  where t2.key = t.key and t2.col1 <> t.col1
                 );
```

This assumes that `col1` is unique per key (as is the case with your data).

This can take advantage of an index on `input_t(key, col1)`.

Comment: This is similar to the first scenario I tried, what if col1 is NULL? I still want key, col2, other columns.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo . . . The first works.  The second version needs a `NULL`-safe comparison, which depends on the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think part of his problem is he's limiting by an aggregate function in the WHERE clause instead of the HAVING clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about either

```
SELECT *
FROM input_t
WHERE key IN (
   SELECT key
   FROM input_t
   GROUP BY key
   HAVING COUNT(key) = 1)
```

or

```
SELECT i.*
FROM 
 input_t i inner join
(select 
  key 
from 
  input_t 
group by 
  key 
having 
  count(key) = 1) k on 
i.key = k.key
```